# Batch encapsulated Powershell code to run without command prompt window still not working

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, scripting, windows-scripting

```
@start "" /min PowerShell.exe -NoLogo -WindowStyle Hidden -NoProfile -NoInteractive -Command "Invoke-Expression -Command ((Get-Content -Path '%~f0' | Select-Object -Skip 3) -join [environment]::NewLine)"
@exit /b 0

REM The line below is PowerShell script command to uninstall Windows 10 apps....
$t = '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindow(int handle, int state);'
add-type -name win -member $t -namespace native
[native.win]::ShowWindow(([System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess() | Get-Process).MainWindowHandle, 0)

Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "2414FC7A.Viber" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "41038Axilesoft.ACGMediaPlayer" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "46928bounde.EclipseManager" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "4DF9E0F8.Netflix" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "64885BlueEdge.OneCalendar" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "7EE7776C.LinkedInforWindows" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "828B5831.HiddenCityMysteryofShadows" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "89006A2E.AutodeskSketchBook" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "9E2F88E3.Twitter" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "A278AB0D.DisneyMagicKingdoms" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "A278AB0D.DragonManiaLegends" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "A278AB0D.MarchofEmpires" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "ActiproSoftwareLLC.562882FEEB491" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "AdobeSystemsIncorporated.AdobePhotoshopExpress" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "CAF9E577.Plex" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "D52A8D61.FarmVille2CountryEscape" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "D5EA27B7.Duolingo-LearnLanguagesforFree" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "DB6EA5DB.CyberLinkMediaSuiteEssentials" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "DolbyLaboratories.DolbyAccess" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "Drawboard.DrawboardPDF" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "E046963F.LenovoCompanion" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "Facebook.Facebook" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "Fitbit.FitbitCoach" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "GAMELOFTSA.Asphalt8Airborne" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "KeeperSecurityInc.Keeper" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "LenovoCorporation.LenovoID" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "LenovoCorporation.LenovoSettings" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "Microsoft.MinecraftUWP" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "Nordcurrent.CookingFever" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "PandoraMediaInc.29680B314EFC2" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "SpotifyAB.SpotifyMusic" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "WinZipComputing.WinZipUniversal" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "XINGAG.XING" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "flaregamesGmbH.RoyalRevolt2" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "king.com.BubbleWitch3Saga" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "king.com.CandyCrushSaga" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers "king.com.CandyCrushSodaSaga" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage

exit
```

The problem with the script above is as follows:

1. The script always popping up Command Prompt window
2. The script is always executed even though the application has already been uninstalled, so there is no way to skip it if the apps are not even listed.

Comment: why do you need the showwindow?

Comment: No, I do not need it. hence I wanted to know how to remove it so it does not show anything on the screen.

Comment: It might be worth showing what things you have tried. As I note on another of your questions, we encourage folks to consider the problem before them before turning to Stack Overflow. Volunteers here want to help others, but they don't want to do their work for them `:-)`.